# Print float/double without trailing zeros?

Tags: c

There are a few questions related to this, but I haven't seen one that correctly answers this question. I want to print a floating-point number, but I want the number of decimal places to be adaptive. As an example:

```
0      -> 0
1234   -> 1234
0.1234 -> 0.1234
0.3    -> 0.3
```

Annoyingly, the `%f` specifier will only print to a fixed precision, so it will add trailing zeros to all numbers that don't reach that precision. Some have suggested the `%g` specifier, which works for a set of numbers, but it will switch to scientific notation for some numbers, like this:

```
printf("%g", 1000000.0); // prints 1e+06
```

How can I print floating-point numbers without the unnecessary zeros, while still maintaining printf's standard accuracy for numbers that actually have fractional components?

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze I don't think that's a duplicate, since it's considerably more involved than I'm looking for. I'm fine with rounding to a few digits, I just don't want any trailing zeros.

Comment: But that's what you've asked for, quote: `How can I print floating-point numbers without the unnecessary zeros, but also without rounding or truncating the value?`

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Ah, so I did, my bad. That was more in reference to "answers" on similar questions that would advise using `%.2f` or similar. I've edited it to remove that language.

Comment: But now the language is vague. Define `fairly good accuracy for numbers that need it`.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze I mean printf's standard accuracy (I believe 6 decimal places) for numbers that actually have decimal components. Again, I don't want it to be super accurate, I'm fine with printf's accuracy, I just hate all the trailing zeros.

Comment: Sorry, but that's still vague. You should've been explained by now that in a binary floating-point number there are no independent decimal digits/components in the fractional part. So, again, what's the question, precisely?

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze We can argue over technicalities, but I don't think this question really warrants it. I understand how floating point works, but it doesn't matter. I'm happy round the numbers, but this question doesn't require a complex understanding of IEEE 754 representation. All I want is the regular printf display of a floating-point number without any trailing zeros, if any. I think that any misunderstanding over that is unwarranted and pointless. I have solved my problem, thanks.

Comment: Oh hey, @JasonC, it’s been a while. How the heck did you find this question, then go out of your way to mark it as a dupe after *three years*? Anyway, it’s appreciated. ;)

Comment: @AlexisKing I stopped playing Factorio for a second to look for how to print floats without trailing zeroes (I'm rusty), and the top zillion Google results were duplicate SO questions.

Comment: @JasonC Hah. Well, I suppose the answer is not very satisfying, is it? Anyway, remember to visit the Tavern sometime—you’re not even pingable anymore and the place is deathly dull these days. :P (Also, these comments will self-destruct.)

Comment: @AlexisKing Yes. The answers bummed me out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `snprintf` to print to a temporary buffer then remove the trailing `'0'` characters manually. There is no other way that's both correct and reasonably easy to implement.

Comment: Nice idea. But `0.1234` will be represented as `0.12339999999999999580335[...]` in an IEEE double. There are no trailing '0' characters.

Comment: Round it to a few times machine precision, then trim zeros.

Comment: @flyingOwl, `snprintf` takes care of that for you. That's the whole point.

Comment: Without `snprintf`, rounding in decimal is **very hard**.

Comment: @R.. Isn't that still technically just truncation, not rounding? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @JakeKing: I was wondering the same. What format specifier is given to snprintf() to get something "better" than printing directly with printf()? How do you know the needed precision?

Comment: The problem is "I want *n* decimal places but don't want to see trailing zeros."

Comment: @Jake: Nope, `printf` rounds.

Comment: @R.. Ah, of course, right. Got a simple working solution using this method. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
printf("%.20g\n", 1000000.0); // = 1000000
```

This will switch to scientific notation after 20 significant digits (default is after 6 digits for "%g"):

```
printf("%.20g\n", 1e+19); // = 10000000000000000000
printf("%.20g\n", 1e+20); // = 1e+20
```

But be careful with double precision:

```
printf("%.20g\n", 0.12345);   // = 0.12345000000000000417
printf("%.15g\n", 0.12345);   // = 0.12345
```

Comment: No dice. `printf("%.15g", 0.00001)` still prints `1e-05`.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that using IEEE standard 754 representation, floating point values (with a fractional part) can never have "trailing zeros".

Trailing zeros mean that the fractional value can be written as `x/10^n` for some integers x, n. But the only fractions that can be represented by this standard have the form `x/2^n` for some integers x, n.

So what you write as 0.1234 is represented using the bytes 0x3D 0xFC 0xB9 0x24. This is:

```
Sign = 0
Exponent = 01111011 (which means -4)
Significand: 1.11111001011100100100100
```

The significand means: 1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + 0/32 + 0/64 + 1/128 + 0/256 + 1/512 + 1/1024 + 1/2048 + 0/4096 + 0/8192 + ...

If you perform this calculation, you get 1.974400043487548828125.

So the number is `+ 1.974400043487548828125 * 2^(-4)` = `0.1234000027179718`

(I've calculated this using a computer, of course, so it could be off for the same reason...)

As you can see, the computer does not want to decide for you that you want to chop this number after 4 digits (only) and not after 9 digits (0.123400002). The point is that the computer doesn't see this number as 0.1234 with an infinite number of trailing zeros.

So I don't think there's a better way than R.'s.

Comment: Understood. So perhaps I want to round to say, 8 decimal places, which would be 0.12340000. I still want to be able to print this rounded value without the extra zeros.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small function to do this myself using the method already mentioned, here it is with a tester. I can't guarantee it's bug free but I think it's fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *convert(char *s, double x);

int main()
{
    char str[3][20];
    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", convert(str[0], 0),
          convert (str[1], 2823.28920000),
          convert (str[2], 4.000342300));

}

char *convert(char *s, double x)
{
    char *buf = malloc(100);
    char *p;
    int ch;

    sprintf(buf, "%.10f", x);
    p = buf + strlen(buf) - 1;
    while (*p == '0' && *p-- != '.');
    *(p+1) = '\0';
    if (*p == '.') *p = '\0';
    strcpy(s, buf);
    free (buf);
    return s;
}
```

Output:

```
0
2823.2892
4.0003423
```

Answer (score -1):

You can print like this:

```
printf("%.0f", 1000000.0);
```

For a more detailed answer, look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

Comment: `printf("%.0f", 0.1234);` prints "0". I don't think the OP wanted that.

Comment: "How can I print floating-point numbers without the unnecessary zeros, but also without rounding or truncating the value?" is the answer
That prints 0, because is doesn't print after dot (fraction part)

Comment: This will truncate the number, won't it?

Comment: @Metabble if you print a variable then that format will not change your variable. It is just a format for printing numbers

Comment: @nabroyan The question specifically says that 0.1234 should be printed as 0.1234. That's not what your answer is doing.

Comment: @OmriBarel that's right, my answer is for cases that you know precision of that number